# How to restrict number entries in R data table without using for loop

Tags: r, dataframe

Please help me out, thanks in advance

I have a large data frame in **R**. A sample is attached here.

```
  event_id       class    value
   1         ERROR       23
   1       WARNING       45
   2       WARNING       12
   2    DIAGNOSTIC       35
   2         ERROR       67
   2       WARNING        1
   3       WARNING       56
   3    DIAGNOSTIC       63
   3          ERROR      56
```

I would like to limit the number of entries per event_id by 2. 
I want to get it without running for loop. 
My expected out is following.

```
  event_id      class   value
    1        ERROR         23
    1      WARNING         45
    2      WARNING         12
    2   DIAGNOSTIC         35
    3      WARNING         56
    3   DIAGNOSTIC         63
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `dplyr`. Assuming your dataset is in `data`:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(event_id) %>%
  filter(row_number() <= 2)
```

will give you the top two results for each `event_id`.

Comment: Base R equivalent: `dat[with(dat, ave(event_id,event_id,FUN=seq) <= 2 ),]`